# Android Smartbanner positioning

Tags: javascript, android, css, banner

I am using this Script for adding the Android Smartbanner for linking my App:
https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js

My Site is ismoker.eu

How can I put the Android Banner in the same way to the top of the Page like the IOS Banner? Here are the two banners which shows what I mean:

iOS Banner Mobile: http://prntscr.com/pdti5k
Android Banner (not outside the Page Div and not visible because Menu is fixed): http://prntscr.com/pdtipm

Answer (score 0):

From `smartbanner.js` point of view there's no difference between how the banner is rendered on iOS and Android.

To fix the issue, try checking if:

1. meta tags for both Android and iOS are defined in the same fashion
2. there's no specifically added `smartbanner--android` CSS class in your application that prevents it from working similarly to iOS

If the above brings no resolution, define the `smartbanner--android` class in your CSS to push the smartbanner down as you need it. The behaviour is likely to be bound to your application's internal styling.